# Robolectric with AndroidX Fragments

Tags: android, robolectric, androidx

How to test AndroidX fragment with Robolectric?

I added `testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4:4.0-alpha-3"` dependency and tried with this code:

```
val controller = SupportFragmentController.setupFragment(
            TestableFragment.buildFragment(DATA),
            TestableFragmentHolderActivity::class.java)
```

`TestableFragment` is `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, and `TestableFragmentHolderActivity` is `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

But I get an error during test:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentController.setupFragment(Landroidx/fragment/app/Fragment;Ljava/lang/Class;)Landroidx/fragment/app/Fragment;

Comment: robolectric currently does not support androidx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new way to test fragments with Robolectric's latest API. Check [the official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing)
You'll need to create a `FragmentScenario`

```
val fragmentScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>()
```

and then test like you usually do with Espresso

```
onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")))
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a robolectric API, but, as I understood, it is a new API for local unit testing of fragments.

Comment: @ufkoku Android team and Robolectric team merged two API into one, basically, they took Espresso API and removed big chunks of Robolectric-specific calls. It still works on top of Robolectric but looks like Espresso.

Comment: Where do we put these tests: in **test** or **androidTest** directory??

Comment: It's *test* folder see examples https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples
AFAIK launching the same test on device and local JVM is not yet supported with gradle (only with Google's own internal Bazel solution)

Comment: How does this allow specifying a parent activity in the Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to this git issue: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3985. New API for AndroidX fragment will be soon released.

Comment: Is it still in beta?

Comment: Robolectric 4 is released http://robolectric.org/blog/2018/10/25/robolectric-4-0/